# Using a backslash and the following by it non-ASCII char

Tags: pdftex, texlive, characters, inline

I'm writing a text with a special char of backslash (`\`), the text requires to containt the char and the following non-ASCII symbol (cyrillic), so for example I type:

```
text \ц other text
```

and I have to get afger compilation:

```
text <special char> other text
```

As you can see the sequence `\ц` should be converted to a `<special char>`. How can I reach that?

I've tried to define that special char like follows:

```
\newcommand{\ц}{\char`\\\char"1089}
```

But the compiler thrown an error. And can't I escape the while block in order to the char `\` is being treated as it is? For example like:

```
\escapetext{text \ц other text}
```

and it will accept the text in the braces as a **plain text**? It seems that I can't use `\verb` for this:

```
\verb$\ц$
```

because it is changing a font out of required one.

**Additionals:**

I have the text with many `\ц`, `\д`, etc sequesnces and the replacement them to a specific sequnces like `\spc{ц}`, etc. seems to me unappropriate because it strongly makes the text sources more complex to write, and read. Some I'll narrow my question to this. Can I use the redefinition:

```
 \newcommand{\ц}{\char`\\\char"1089}
```

with `luatex` or `xelatex`?

Comment: Are you using `pdflatex` or `xelatex/lualatex`?

Comment: @egreg i've specified [tag:texlive] =)

Comment: It means nothing, sorry. Can you add a minimal example?

Comment: @egreg ah, ok, `pdflatex`

Comment: texlive includes pdftex xetex and luatex the last two are based on Unicode and can define such command names but classic tex including pdftex can not define commands of this form

Comment: `\newcommand{\ц}{\char\`\\\char"1089}` pdftex can not define a command `\ц` and it can not have numbers bigger than `"FF` as the argument to `\char`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle well, which is the solution?

Comment: It is not clear what the question is, then the solution would be easier to give. You have given some tex commands that do not work but have not said what they are supposed to do. what output do you want? If you say that, someone could tell you some input that would work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle for example the solution for the `\newcommand{\ц} {\char`\\\char"1089}` to make it working

Comment: egreg has taken a guess, but in general if you just post code that generates errors and say "make it work" it is impossible to help, you know what you wanted it to do, I only know that it is a syntax error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't define a command of that type in `pdflatex`, but you can use a different approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\newcommand\spc[1]{%
  \symbol{`\\}% the backslash
  #1% the letter
}

\begin{document}

text \spc{ц} other text

\end{document}
```

[image]

You *might* also do

```
\def\ц{\spc{ц}}
```

and then

```
text \ц other text
```

would work, but it's a hack and ***only one*** command of this kind can be defined.

For “escaping” arbitrary cyrillic characters, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\newcommand\spc[1]{%
  \symbol{`\\}% the backslash
  #1% the letter
}

\def\^^d0#1{\spc{^^d0#1}}
\def\^^d1#1{\spc{^^d1#1}}


\begin{document}

text \ц other text

text \э other text

\end{document}
```

[image]

### How does it work?

The proposed macros exploit how a UTF-8 file is read in by `pdftex`, which, I recall, is an 8 bit engine. Base Cyrillic characters in Unicode are at positions U+0400 to U+047F and they are represented by UTF-8 as pairs prefixed by `<D0>` and `<D1>`. For instance, ц is represented by the two bytes `<D1><86>`.

In TeX one can represent a byte by the notation `^^xy`, where `xy` is a pair of (lowercase) hexadecimal digits (`0123456789abcdef`).

So I define control symbols `\^^d0` and `\^^d1` to retrieve the subsequent byte, print the backslash and put back the first and second byte to be interpreted in the usual way by `inputenc` with the option `utf8`.

Comment: Thanx, I know that the replacement  `\ц` to `\spc{ц}` is allowed, but i'm trying to minimize the changes into the original text, which contains many `\ц` and other similar chars.

Comment: Is there a solution for `xelatex/lualatex`?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ For `xelatex/lualatex` just do `\newcommand{\ц}{\spc{ц}}` (keeping the same definition of `\spc`)

Comment: thanx, is that (second part) solution for `pdftex` or for other preprocessors?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ The solution with `\def\^^d0...` is for `pdflatex` only.

Comment: and one more, could you in short words explain the does `\def\^^d0... \def\^^d1` lines mean?