# Ligature with a char inserted by \symbol command is ignored by pdftex

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I have some change to a virtual font like this:

```
(LABEL C 9)
(LIG O 344 C L) (comment д L)
(STOP)
(LABEL O 346) (comment ж)
(LIG C 7 C 9) (comment 7 9)
(LIG O 134 C 9) (comment backslash 9)
(STOP)
```

It should give me ligature conversions: `ж` + `7` -> `9`, `ж` + `\` -> `9`, `9` + `д` -> `L`. The font forward, and backward compilation geves me the similar `.vpl` font source file (just without comments). After the font installation when I try to build a `.pdf` from `.tex`, the resulted `.pdf` is strange. the rule where backslash is being used after the first ligature transformation, the second hasn't been happened, while if there was no backslash char, it has. So the `tex` source:

```
ж\д ж7д 9д
```

will be converted into:

```
9д L L
```

So questions are: What blocks the `pdftex` to render for me the correct ligature, when backslash is used? and the second is how to fix it?

**Update**

The `.vpl`

```
(VTITLE Created by afm2tfm irmucs.afm -O -u -v irmucsv.vpl -T orthucs8.enc)
(FAMILY TEX-IRMUCS)
(FACE F MRR)
(CODINGSCHEME ORTUCS8TOT2AENCODING)
(DESIGNSIZE R 10.0)
(COMMENT DESIGNSIZE IS IN POINTS)
(COMMENT OTHER SIZES ARE MULTIPLES OF DESIGNSIZE)
(CHECKSUM O 1124771264)
(FONTDIMEN
   (SLANT R 0.0)
   (SPACE R 0.5)
   (STRETCH R 0.2)
   (SHRINK R 0.1)
   (XHEIGHT R 0.487)
   (QUAD R 1.0)
   (EXTRASPACE R 0.111)
   )
(MAPFONT D 0
   (FONTNAME irmucs)
   (FONTCHECKSUM O 1124771264)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )
(LIGTABLE
   (LABEL C 9) (comment zqivete_pod_vzmetom)
   (LIG C d C L) (comment zqivete_pod_vzmetom + dobrotitlo -> zqivete_pod_dobrotitlom)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C L)
   (KRN C q R 0.005)
   (KRN O 240 R 0.005)
   (KRN C b R 0.005)
   (KRN O 135 R -0.007)
   (KRN C W R -0.018)
   (KRN O 100 R 0.005)
   (KRN O 247 R -0.018)
   (KRN O 206 R 0.005)
   (KRN O 255 R 0.005)
   (KRN O 224 R -0.007)
   (KRN O 223 R 0.005)
   (KRN C m R -0.01)
   (KRN C l R -0.008)
   (KRN C k R -0.008)
   (KRN O 263 R -0.013)
   (KRN C h R -0.01)
   (KRN O 267 R -0.013)
   (KRN O 255 R -0.017)
   (KRN O 135 R -0.017)
   (KRN O 134 R -0.01)
   (KRN O 337 R -0.008)
   (KRN C W R -0.013)
   (KRN C U R -0.006)
   (KRN C T R -0.01)
   (KRN O 275 R -0.006)
   (KRN C R R -0.01)
   (KRN C N R -0.01)
   (KRN O 16 R -0.006)
   (KRN C G R -0.01)
   (KRN C F R -0.006)
   (KRN O 222 R -0.013)
   (KRN O 265 R -0.01)
   (KRN O 247 R -0.013)
   (KRN O 246 R -0.006)
   (KRN O 233 R -0.017)
   (KRN O 231 R -0.01)
   (KRN O 211 R -0.01)
   (KRN O 174 R -0.01)
   (KRN O 173 R -0.006)
   (KRN O 377 R -0.01)
   (KRN C 2 R -0.006)
   (KRN C w R -0.013)
   (KRN C v R -0.017)
   (KRN C u R -0.008)
   (KRN C t R -0.013)
   (KRN O 276 R -0.01)
   (KRN O 230 R -0.017)
   (KRN O 240 R -0.01)
   (KRN C n R -0.01)
   (KRN C m R -0.017)
   (KRN C f R -0.024)
   (KRN O 252 R -0.013)
   (KRN C Y R -0.006)
   (KRN O 275 R -0.01)
   (KRN O 202 R -0.013)
   (KRN O 222 R -0.013)
   (KRN O 224 R -0.017)
   (KRN O 51 R -0.051)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 344)
   (LIG O 267 C D)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 346)
   (LIG O 176 C 9)
   (LIG C 7 C 9) (comment digit7 digit9)
   (LIG O 134 C 9) (comment backslash digit9)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 134) (comment backslash)
   (KRN C m R -0.031)
   (KRN C l R -0.03)
   (KRN C k R -0.03)
   (KRN O 263 R -0.052)
   (KRN O 252 R -0.018)
   (KRN C d R -0.019)
   (KRN O 267 R -0.019)
   (KRN O 255 R -0.069)
   (KRN O 135 R -0.035)
   (KRN C W R -0.062)
   (KRN C V R -0.019)
   (KRN C U R -0.041)
   (KRN O 275 R -0.007)
   (KRN C R R -0.034)
   (KRN C Q R -0.015)
   (KRN O 254 R -0.014)
   (KRN C N R -0.015)
   (KRN C M R -0.008)
   (KRN C G R -0.022)
   (KRN C F R -0.012)
   (KRN O 222 R -0.011)
   (KRN O 224 R -0.008)
   (KRN O 265 R -0.068)
   (KRN O 251 R -0.015)
   (KRN O 247 R -0.062)
   (KRN O 246 R -0.041)
   (KRN O 233 R -0.069)
   (KRN O 231 R -0.034)
   (KRN O 174 R -0.031)
   (KRN O 173 R -0.007)
   (KRN C 2 R -0.007)
   (KRN C w R -0.052)
   (KRN C v R -0.069)
   (KRN C u R -0.03)
   (KRN C t R -0.052)
   (KRN C q R -0.035)
   (KRN O 230 R -0.096)
   (KRN O 240 R -0.031)
   (KRN C n R -0.031)
   (KRN C m R -0.069)
   (KRN C f R -0.019)
   (KRN O 252 R -0.011)
   (KRN C Y R -0.007)
   (KRN O 202 R -0.052)
   (KRN O 222 R -0.011)
   (KRN O 224 R -0.035)
   (KRN O 52 R -0.111)
   (KRN O 51 R -0.07)
   (LIG O 344 O 144) (comment backslash + dobro -> d)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C d)
   (KRN C q R -0.013)
   (KRN O 240 R -0.013)
   (KRN C l R -0.011)
   (KRN C k R -0.011)
   (KRN O 210 R -0.015)
   (KRN O 263 R -0.011)
   (KRN C h R -0.015)
   (KRN C d R -0.019)
   (KRN O 267 R -0.011)
   (KRN C b R -0.013)
   (KRN O 255 R -0.042)
   (KRN O 137 R -0.015)
   (KRN O 337 R -0.008)
   (KRN C W R -0.056)
   (KRN C U R -0.033)
   (KRN C L R -0.015)
   (KRN O 221 R -0.015)
   (KRN C F R -0.012)
   (KRN O 222 R -0.011)
   (KRN C D R -0.027)
   (KRN O 224 R -0.007)
   (KRN O 100 R -0.013)
   (KRN O 265 R -0.037)
   (KRN O 261 R -0.015)
   (KRN O 247 R -0.056)
   (KRN O 246 R -0.033)
   (KRN O 233 R -0.042)
   (KRN O 211 R -0.015)
   (KRN O 206 R -0.013)
   (KRN O 377 R -0.015)
   (KRN C w R -0.011)
   (KRN C v R -0.042)
   (KRN C u R -0.011)
   (KRN C t R -0.018)
   (KRN O 276 R -0.015)
   (KRN O 230 R -0.049)
   (KRN C m R -0.042)
   (KRN C l R -0.015)
   (KRN C k R -0.015)
   (KRN C f R -0.062)
   (KRN O 252 R -0.011)
   (KRN O 255 R -0.013)
   (KRN O 275 R -0.015)
   (KRN C L R -0.015)
   (KRN O 202 R -0.011)
   (KRN O 222 R -0.011)
   (KRN C D R -0.027)
   (KRN O 223 R -0.013)
   (KRN O 57 R -0.045)
   (KRN O 54 R -0.033)
   (KRN O 52 R -0.115)
   (KRN O 51 R -0.069)
   (STOP)
   )
(CHARACTER C 7
   (CHARWD R 0.001)
   (CHARHT R 0.88)
   (CHARDP R 0.2)
   (MAP
      (SETCHAR C 7)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C 9
   (CHARWD R 0.684)
   (CHARHT R 0.88)
   (CHARDP R 0.2)
   (MAP
      (SETCHAR C 9)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C L
   (CHARWD R 0.426)
   (CHARHT R 0.88)
   (CHARDP R 0.2)
   (CHARIC R 0.047)
   (MAP
      (SETCHAR C L)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 134
   (CHARWD R 0.001)
   (CHARHT R 0.88)
   (CHARDP R 0.2)
   (MAP
      (SETCHAR O 134)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C d
   (CHARWD R 0.001)
   (CHARHT R 0.88)
   (CHARDP R 0.2)
   (MAP
      (SETCHAR C d)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 344
   (CHARWD R 0.402)
   (CHARHT R 0.88)
   (CHARDP R 0.2)
   (MAP
      (SETCHAR O 344)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 346
   (CHARWD R 0.684)
   (CHARHT R 0.88)
   (CHARDP R 0.2)
   (MAP
      (SETCHAR O 346)
      )
   )
```

I've tried with and wothout the line `(LIG O 344 O 144) (comment backslash + dobro -> d)`

And the `.tex`:

```
$ cat hello.tex
\documentclass[12pt,a6paper,twoside,dvips,civil=antiqua,cs=irmologion]{hipbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

ж\д ж~д ж7д 9д

\end{document}
```

Also I've used the changes to `backslash` behaviour of [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225719/71279), as:

```
\newcommand\spc[1]{%
  \symbol{`\\}% the backslash
  #1% the letter
}

\def\^^d0#1{\spc{^^d0#1}}
\def\^^d1#1{\spc{^^d1#1}}
```

Comment: do you have catcodes set appropriately, normally input of `\д ` is the command with name `д` rather than the two characters `\ ` and `д` to be typeset?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, you can see it in 1st case, when ж\ is being converted to the proper ligature 9

Comment: Without looking at the font you have not changed the catcode of `\ ` so `\д` is a single command of that name, not two characters, which is what I asked about earlier?

Comment: I don't have hipbook so I changed it to `article` then, as expected I get `! Undefined control sequence.`

Comment: > Also I've used the changes to backslash behaviour of here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225719/71279

Comment: yes but (a) the code in your example doesn't do that (unless it is in the class that you have not shown, so we can not run your example) and (b) are you sure (I can't test as you have posted no code)  that those macros never insert `{}` ?? `{f}{f}` does not ligature. In either case, the answer to my question about catcodes in the first comment is "no" not "yes"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but why then the first ligature is correctly converted?

Comment: If you posted an example that allowed us to trace the code, perhaps we could trace it.

Comment: are you using `\symbol` ? note `ff, \char\`f\char\`f, \symbol{\`f}\symbol{\`f}` the first two ligature, the last does not.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just use the direct replacement the command \д to the two chars \ and д.

Comment: without an example to test impossible to guess, sorry.

Comment: In earlier comments you said you used the code in the linked answer which uses `\symbol` but now you say you don't use `\symbol`, and you haven't posted a tex file that is usable. If you use `\symbol` ligatures are suppressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The referenced code uses `\symbol`, the definition of which ends in `\relax` so suppresses ligatures with following but not preceding characters.

using an example that can be run:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\showoutput

1 ff
2 f\relax f 
3 \symbol{`f}f
4 f\symbol{`f}

\end{document}
```

produces

```
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 1
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10  (ligature ff)
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 2
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 f
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 f
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 3
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 f
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 f
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 4
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10  (ligature ff)
```

Where the last example with `\symbol` as the second character produces a ligature, but using `\symbol` as the first character does not.

This matches the observed behaviour as far as I can tell, so I would guess that is the issue.

You could use

```
\char`\f
```

instead of

```
\symbol{f}
```

(with backslash instead of f in your example)
or you could, as indicated in the initial comment, change the catcode of `\` making it a normal character for example after

```
 \catcode`\/=0
 \catcode`\\=12
```

then `\` will be a normal character that just typesets as itself and command names such as begin and end must be accessed as `/begin` and `/end`